# In perl, how do I replace a set of characters with a different set of characters in a single pass?

Tags: perl

Given ...

```
Ax~B~xCx~xDx
```

... emit ...

```
A~-B-~C~-~D~
```

I want to replace the ~ characters with - and the x characters with ~.

I could write ...

```
s/~/-/g;s/x/~/g;
```

... but that (looks like it) passes over the string twice.

Comment: Why use RegEx? Why not just iterate over the string yourself?

Comment: Because this... is... PEEEEEEEEEERL!!!! Nah more seriously, regexes are way shorter and faster than having to write the whole stuff.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Because if I iterate over the string myself, I am writing C (or FORTRAN?) in perl, and the goal is to write perl.

Comment: regexes are absolutely not the Right Tool for this job. tr/// is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use "transliterate" for replacement based on characters. Try this:

```
tr/~x/\-~/;
```

Comment: "transliterate", not "translate"

Comment: The square brackets are unneeded and useless here.

Comment: You're probably right, but [I was taught wrong](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#DoingTranslations).

Comment: `tr/~x/-~/` is what you are looking for. Your transliteration is not using the regex metacharacters, it is treating them like string literals, replacing `[` with `[`, `,` with `,`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with single characters, tr/// is the obvious answer:

```
tr/~x/-~/;
```

However, you're going to need s/// to deal with longer sequences:

```
my %subs = ( '~' => '-', 'x' => '~' );
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %subs;
s/($pat)/$subs{$1}/g;
```